# performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: is not passing an argument as expected

Tags: swift

I am using `performSelector` to control the execution time of some methods in my controller. I would expect in this case the argument passed to `animateIntroViews` to be the value of `with` however it is not, instead it is some massively negative number like `-7878379202283`

```
func runOnRenderAnimations() -> Void {        
    perform(#selector(animateIntroViews), with: 0, afterDelay: 0.5)
    perform(#selector(animateIntroViews), with: 1, afterDelay: 2.5)
}

@objc fileprivate func animateIntroViews(textPosition: Int) -> Void {
    print(textPosition)
}
```

Comment: Going by the names of your methods, it looks like you are trying to trigger timed animations, is there any reason why you could not use `UIView.animateKeyFrames` to create your animation? It seems purpose built for this use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`perform` doesn't work with parameters of primitive types like `Int`.

A better solution is to use `DispatchQueue asyncAfter`. This allows you to call the method normally.

```
func runOnRenderAnimations() -> Void {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: now() + 0.5) {
        self.animateIntroViews(textPosition: 0)
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: now() + 2.5) {
        self.animateIntroViews(textPosition: 1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With your `perform` selector, you can pass argument as `NSNumber` instead of `Int` and get it as `Number` and Convert it to `Int` in your `animateIntroViews` function.

Example:

```
func runOnRenderAnimations() -> Void {

    perform(#selector(animateIntroViews), with: NSNumber(value: 0), afterDelay: 0.5)
    perform(#selector(animateIntroViews), with: NSNumber(value: 1), afterDelay: 2.5)
}

@objc fileprivate func animateIntroViews(textPosition: NSNumber) -> Void {

    print(textPosition.intValue)
}
```

Comment: While this works, it's best to avoid this as it is making use of a lot of old Objective-C features. Even in Objective-C, you would use a dispatch queue and async_after instead of `perform`.

Comment: Yeah you are correct. But if you want to cancel the timer function, it's easy to handle in `perform`. You can just call `NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(animateIntroViews), object: NSNumber(value: 0))`. So that I answered to support with his existing code.